# RCP application missing required jar

Tags: maven, eclipse-rcp, rcp, tycho

I'm trying to build an RCP application which I've revived from an old project which was originally using a PDE build. The porting to maven was accomplished with the help of Tycho and I'm now able to create an eclipse.exe under Windows. The application uses a bundle and feature. The build is targeted to an Eclipse in the version Mars.

The directory structure looks like this:

```
parent dir -
  - dfi-admin-bundle (packaging eclipse-plugin)
  - dfi-admin-feature (packaging eclipse-feature)
  - dfi-admin-mars (holds the eclipse-target-definition)
  - dfi-p2deps (with a p2 repository created with p2-maven-plugin)
  - dfi-eclipse-repository (packaging eclipse-repository and creates the
    product using tycho-p2-director-plugin and the materialize-products goal)
```

Everything is looking good until I start the application. Then I get a window telling me about an error and logfile. The logfile shows me a missing class.

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error starting module.
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:580)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:327)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:402)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:573)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:191)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
at de.danet.dfi.gui.admin.Activator.<clinit>(Activator.java:13)
```

I'm figuring that the problem is the missing jar containing the implementation of LoggerFactory. This is the reason I set up the dfi-p2deps directory with the p2 repository. In this repository I have log4j.over.slf4j_1.7.14.jar and slf4j.api_1.7.14.jar in the repository/plugins directory. The generated product does not contain the two jars in the plugins directory from the p2 repository I created.

If I understand correctly I need to declare this dependency in the META/MANIFEST.MF file of the bundle, but I can't seem to get this working at all. Maybe it's not the right approach.

BTW, this happens regardless of the setting of pomDependencies within the org.eclipse.tycho:target-platform-configuration. (*consider* or empty)

Does anyone have a tip for me as to how configure the build to add the needed jars to the RCP. I'm figuring that these errors for missing logging class is just the tip of the iceberg and that many more missing dependencies are going to show up.

Here's the content of the dfi-admin-feature/feature.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feature
      id="dfi-admin-feature"
      label="%featureName"
      version="0.2.1.qualifier">

   <description>
      %description
   </description>

   <copyright>
      %copyright
   </copyright>

   <license url="%licenseURL">
      %license
   </license>

   <plugin
         id="dfi-admin-bundle"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>
```

And the product file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?pde version="3.5"?>

<product name="DFI-Admin Product" uid="dfi-admin.product.id" id="dfi-admin.product" application="dfi-admin-bundle.application" version="0.2.0.qualifier" useFeatures="true" includeLaunchers="true">

   <configIni use="default">
   </configIni>

   <launcherArgs>
   </launcherArgs>

   <plugins>
   </plugins>

   <features>
      <feature id="dfi-admin-feature"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.rcp"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.user.ui"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.httpclient4.feature"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.httpclient4.ssl.feature"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.extras.feature"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.emf.common"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.feature"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.ecf.core.feature"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.rcp.feature"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.feature"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.ecf.core.ssl.feature"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.ssl.feature"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.e4.rcp"/>
   </features>

   <configurations>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime" autoStart="true" startLevel="4" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.common" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.ds" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.event" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins" autoStart="true" startLevel="4" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator" autoStart="true" startLevel="1" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.update.configurator" autoStart="true" startLevel="4" />
      <property name="org.eclipse.update.reconcile" value="false" />
   </configurations>

</product>
```

Comment: It sounds like the logger plug-in is missing in the feature being built. Could you please show your `feature.xml`?

Comment: Sure, I added it to the end of the question.

Comment: And the `*.product` does contain this feature, right?

Comment: Yes it does. I added the dfi-admin.product file to the question.

Comment: If you build only the feature instead of the whole application, does it include the bundle? Does changing the feature version number so that it does not start with `0.` change something?

Comment: 1) The feature has the dfi-admin-bundle defined as a plugin, and the dfi-admin-bundle shows up in the p2content.xml in the dfi-admin-feature target directory:
./target/p2content.xml:      <required namespace='org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu' name='dfi-admin-bundle' range='[0.1.0.201901091634,0.1.0.201901091634]'/>

2) Changing the version number from 0.2.1 to 1.2.1 doesn't change the problem.

Comment: The only thing I could think of is that there is an older product or feature in the p2 repository with a higher version number that is mistakenly used when building (which is rather unlikely). I'm sorry I can't help you.